# Convert mm/dd/yyyy to yyyy-mm-dd in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, datetime

The date column that I have is in `varchar2` and I want to convert those values in `YYYY-MM-DD`

```
DATE
7/26/2013
7/29/2013
8/1/2013 
8/4/2013 
7/28/2013
7/31/2013
8/3/2013 
7/30/2013
8/5/2013 
7/25/2013
8/2/2013 
8/6/2013 
7/27/2013
```

Comment: SELECT TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(datecol, 'MM/DD/YYYY'),'YYYY-MM-DD')
from YourTable

Comment: Why is this tagged SQL Server? I know Monty Python is all jokes but that just seems wrong.

Comment: Aaron Bertrand - I don't see a SQL Server tag, sire. :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### You should ***never*** store dates in a `VARCHAR` column

So in order to display it differently now, you need to first convert the string to a date and then back to a string

If you are certain that all "dates" do have the right (and same) format, then the following should work:

```
select to_char(to_date(date, 'mm/dd/yyyy'), 'yyyy-mm-dd')
from the_table;
```

But I wouldn't be surprised if that gives you an error because one or more rows have a date which is formatted differently. Something which could not have happened had you defined the column to be of type `DATE` right from the beginning.

You should really, really consider changing that column to be a real `DATE` column.

Btw: `DATE` is a horrible name for such a column. It is a reserved word and it simply doesn't tell you anything about what is actually stored in that column (a "start date", an "end date", a "birth date", a "due date", ...)

Comment: I know we shouldn't but what do I tell those guys who have created the data warehouse and are not freaking us out with 15 different formats of dates in a single columns. What do I tell them?

Comment: @MontyPython: tell them that this is a **very** bad way to store a date. This should be considered a critical bug which needs to be fixed immediately. You may refer to this thread if you want to :)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name - I am already aware of that but they don't seem to care. It's the data analysis team that suffers from such stupid database schemes.

Answer (score 2):

You have to convert your string to `date` and than convert to `char` with expected format

```
select TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(datecol, 'MM/DD/YYYY'),'YYYY-MM-DD')
from your_table
```

[**Sql Fiddle Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d41d8/15531/0)

Answer (score 0):

```
select to_char(TO_DATE("Date", 'MM/DD/YYYY'),'yyyy-mm-dd')
from Table1
```

**[SQL FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/1ca94/6)**

Comment: OP's column with date is `varchar2` not `timestamp`

Answer (score 0):

you can use REGEXP_REPLACE function to manipulate strings or to_date and to_char to convert string to date and than to string back with different format.